# Incorrect syntax near ')' Error in the CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the following CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH PRODUCTION_CTE(ShortProdNo,BoatRefNumber,ProdNo, CustomerPoNumber,LoadDate, Trailer, VeadaBuilding)
AS 
(
    SELECT 
    FBS.BoatNumber AS ShortProdNo,
    UOD.BoatRefNumber AS BoatRefNumber,
    FBS.ProdNo AS ProdNo,
    UOD.CustomerPoNumber AS CustomerPoNumber,
    FBS.Shipped AS LoadDate, 
    FBS.TruckNum AS Trailer,
    (CASE 
    WHEN Rtrim(UOD.CustomerPoNumber)='VEADA-VS1' THEN  'Bldg10'
     ELSE 'Bldg4'
     END) AS VeadaBuilding
FROM SysproCompanyV.dbo.FlatBenningtonShipping as FBS
INNER JOIN SysproCompanyV.dbo.UsrOrderDetails as UOD
ON FBS.BoatNumber=UOD.BoatRefNumber)
```

I am getting the following Error from the above CTE:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I am not sure why it is happening as Inner Joins are allowed in the CTE, all the parenthesis are closed and the names are correctly declared.

Comment: `UOD..BoatRefNumber` you have 2 periods on this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (i.e. `PRODUCTION_CTE`) IMMEDIATE after declaration :

```
;with PRODUCTION_CTE as (
      . . . 
)

select pc.*
from PRODUCTION_CTE pc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!